# Image Magick - Circle Cropping command now failing

Tags: imagemagick

I know this topic has been covered in some depth previously, but one of the recommended methods seems to have stopped working between v5 and V7 in Windows.

magick input.jpg ( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -draw "circle %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h/2)] %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h)]" ) -channel-fx "| gray=>alpha" output.png

Not working in Windows, magick V7.

error is that:-
'gray' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Would someone let me know what the correct syntax is for this method in V7 please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works fine for me in Imagemagick 7.1.1.6 Mac OSX Monterey.

```
magick lena.jpg \( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -draw "circle %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h/2)] %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h)]" \) -channel-fx "| gray=>alpha" output.png
```

[image]

*If you are running that in a .bat file, you need to double your % to  %%.*

**ADDITION**

The circle works by specifying a center point and then some other point on the circumference. In the above, the center is specified and then a point at the same x value, but the y value is at the bottom of the image.

Another way to do it is to translate the origin from the top left to the center of the image and then draw from the new origin (center) to any point, for example the right side of the image (which is half of the width from the center to the side).

```
magick lena.jpg \( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -draw "translate %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h/2)] circle 0,0 %[fx:int(w/2)],0" \) -channel-fx "| gray=>alpha" output.png
```

[image]

Comment: Aha. That's a trick I didn't know. Thank you fmw42. 
Just now need to work out how to set the circle diameter to match the width, rather than the height.

Comment: Do you want the smaller of w or h?  If so use %[fx:min(w,h)/2]. If you just want the width (even if larger than height), use %[fx:w/2] in place of %[fx:h/2]

Comment: So I have interpreted your second suggestion as:- 
"circle %%[fx:int(w/2)],%%[fx:int(w/2)] %%[fx:int(w/2)],%%[fx:int(h)]"
On my machine this leaves the top and left and right untouched and radius's just the bottom. 
I tried for some hours last night to fathom out how this coding works, and I failed to get the logic at all. Thanks for the pointers though.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer

Comment: So simple when its clear...
"circle %%[fx:int(w/2)],%%[fx:int(h/2)] %%[fx:int(w)],%%[fx:int(h/2)]"
Many thanks again to you fmw42. :-)

Comment: If this was helpful, please consider giving it an upvote

Comment: Pleasure. Hopefully I've done that correctly.